# Getting "Script at 'https://example.com/webworker.js' cannot be accessed from origin www.example.com" even with CNAME redirecting www. to main domain

Tags: javascript, dns, web-worker

I'm getting an issue where if I access a website I'm making via [www.example.com/page](http://www.example.com/page) then the browser fails to initialize the web workers.

From what I've read this is expected behaviour for security purposes. And that's fine, but I anticipate some people will be coming to the site via [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) while others will just type in example.com, and I'll need both to be able to access all the site's resources.

I figure the easy way to do this is to change [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) from an @ record to a CNAME record, redirecting all calls to https://www.example.com/page instead to https://example.com/page

I did that last night, and the TTL on the old record was only 30m, so even the world's slowest DNS caches should have been updated by now.

But if I try to access the site via [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) I'm still getting the same domain origin error.

What am I missing here? And most importantly, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNAME records are not HTTP redirects.

The browser looks for `www.example.com`, makes a DNS lookup for it, and the underlying DNS client gets told that the IP address is the same as `example.com`'s, so it gets `example.com`'s IP address and then makes an HTTP request to that IP address asking for `www.example.com`.

The `origin` will still be `https://www.example.com`.

---

Configure your HTTP server to issue a `301 Moved Permanently` redirect for any requests for `www.example.com` instead.